# Compare parameter to the class itself (this) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

A simple case:

```
// A common base class
class A {
}

class B extends A {
    getSomething(parent?: A): number {
        if (!parent || parent == this) {
            return 42;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

However, `this` cannot be used as I did. The error from the TS compiler is:

> 'Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'A' and 'this'.'

Not really helpful. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting from the typescript compiler?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: What's the definition of `B` ?

Comment: True, the example wasn't complete as I just wanted to show the principle and what I'm after. I changed the code a bit, to make this clearer.

Comment: what's the version of the typescript compiler you're using? it looks like it was fixed, I updated my answer

Comment: I'm using the one that comes with VS code (2.1.4). But it turned out that this error was a follow up error, from something that made class B incomplete, which in turn made the this comparison fail. After fixing the class also the comparsion started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to know if the object passed in as a parameter is the same as the object itself.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
    getSomething(parent?: A): number {
        if (parent == this) {
            return 42;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I just ran that code in the TypeScript compiler playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

And it did not compile, perhaps it's time to upgrade your typescript compiler?

(My previous answer was about union types but that is no longer relevant since you updated your question).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make clear that the class and the parameter type actually belong to the same base class. I have updated my question. A union type is not feasible here as this is actually a full class hierarchy where this example stems from.

Comment: Answer inspired me to look deeper if the error is on my side.